# JPA @MappedSuperclass not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having trouble using the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.

Here is a slimmed-down version that demonstrates my confusion.

Superclass:

```java
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public class FooBase {

  @Id
  protected Long id;

  // Getters/setters.

}
```

Subclass:

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Foo extends FooBase {

  String bar;

  // Getters/setters.

}
```

I must be missing something here. Even IntelliJ reports the `Foo` class

> Persistent entity 'Foo' should have primary key

And when I call `JpaRepository#findAll()`, the fields in `Foo` are not present in the JSON response entity.

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you sure that the value of the `bar` in the database is not `NULL`?

Comment: Positive. And the query is definitely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who answered my question.

My problem was not defining getters for subclass fields. Very silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a subclass to inherit fields from a MappedSuperClass, the access modifier must be at least protected or in any case, public.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `bar` property to `private`.

Object returned by JPA call is probably proxy object. It's possible that the `bar` property is accessed directly instead of using getter when serialized to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

usually that message

> Persistent entity 'Foo' should have primary key

is received when the classes are not registered in the persistence.xml file.
while some implementations do not even require persistence.xml file i have noticed that intelij will complain about it if its not there.

so i think creating a persistence.xml file (if you dont have one already) in your resources folder and set the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             version="2.1"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">

        <class>com.your.company.Foo</class>
        <class>com.your.company.Bar</class>
      


        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your pom file, it should look something like this:

```
<project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>net.javaguides.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>hibernate-mappedsuperclass-example</artifactId>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```